# Best practice around using UIViews as containers for background etc

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface, interface-builder

While designing the views in IB, i find it simple to use the UIVIews as containers for other controls. I use this to give a special background color etc..

Is this a good practice or should i be doing something else ? I guess i could programmatically draw a Rectangle. But i'm trying to leverage IB as much as i can.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think so. I also tend to use UIViews to group together controls that need to be changed together e.g. hiding a group of buttons.
I don't believe there is a performance penalty from doing this.

Re: Interface Builder, I guess it all depends on what you feel confortable with. You can also create UIView containers programatically ;)

Comment: i haven't programmed UI elements in code since the 90s. its just so urggh. designers, designers, designers